# prestashop in paypal customer send payment error

Tags: prestashop-1.7

If I pay by Customer Paypal then error message arrives
We’re sorry. This seller doesn’t accept payments in your currency. Please return to the seller and choose another way to pay. return merchant
any idea how solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Which currency have you activated on your shop? Do you check the currencies with which you want to pay and accept by Paypal?

Regards,